# Vulkan Memory Allocator Implementation Errors after #define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION

Tags: c++, memory, allocation, vulkan

Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2019

I am following https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-3/triangle_mesh_code/ and it mentions to add `#include "vk_mem_alloc.h"` and if you compile you will get linker errors.  Then it describes that you should put `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` above the include in the `vk_engine.cpp`.  I understand how this works, and I have only included the define once in the `.cpp` file.

**Issues**: before compiling that state 'declaration is incompatible with ...' for some various functions throughout the header.  Trying to compile gives me errors:

> m_Lock unknown override specifier

> m_Lock undeclared specifer

> InitializeSWRLock is undefined

These issues range from lines 4089-4097, if you base it off the version of VMA found in the "all chapters" link below.

I even downloaded https://github.com/vblanco20-1/vulkan-guide/tree/all-chapters and tried to compile chapter 3, but I get the same issues. On the same lines.  I am able to compile chapters 0, 1, and 2, but for some reason the `#define VMA_IMPLEMENTATION` gives me those specific errors, and I am unable to find out much about them online.

**EDIT:**
**Solution:** Enable C++17 in your compiler
I noticed that the C++ standard was C++14 and when I changed it to C++17 if started to compile.  cmake from the tutorial doesn't automatically set the standard to C++17.  Thank you to those who commented while I was working at this and hopefully this helps another programmer

Comment: Could we get the full (and ugly) error message?

Comment: *"InitializeSWRLock() is undefined*" - does your Windows SDK have `synchapi.h`, and does `windows.h` include it? If not, you need an updated SDK. Or, maybe you simply have `_WIN32_WINNT` set too low in your project, it needs to be at least `0x0600` as `InitializeSWRLock()` was introduced in Windows Vista.

Comment: I think I was able to solve the issue a little while after I had posted this.  It turns out that I needed to have C++17 enabled.  Once I enabled it in visual studio it was able to compile.  Thank you for your comments.  I should probably mark this as answered if I can.